# How to ensure sequential execution of asynchronous calls in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, suspend

```
class BlockEventManager(private val scope: CoroutineScope) {...}
    
private val blockEventManager = BlockEventManager(viewModelScope) ...

fun doSomethingUsefulOneAsync() {
    'some remote service call
}

fun doSomethingUsefulTwoAsync() {
    'some other remote service call dependent on doSomethingUsefulOneAsync()
}
```

How do we achieve if *doSomethingUsefulOneAsync* has completed then execute *doSomethingUsefulTwoAsync*. I don't believe async.await() is set up for this right?

```
blockEventManager.startBlockingAsyncWork {
    val step1 = async { doSomethingUsefulOneAsync() }
    step1.await()
    doSomethingUsefultwoAsync() //will this execute only after step1 completes or fails?
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `blockEventManager` is, but I'm assuming `startBlockingAsyncWork` takes a suspend function as a parameter and invokes it in a coroutine.

One of the key features of coroutines is structured concurrency, and it is absolutely guaranteed that your calls are sequential, so calling `await` on the first Deferred guarantees that `doSomethingUsefulOneAsync()` will return before the execution flow continues.

However, if you want to do these actions sequentially, you shouldn't introduce `async` in the first place. Just call the two functions, one after the other.

It's a code smell that a `suspend` function would ever have the term "async" in its name. A *properly composed* suspend function does its work in a suspending way and then returns its result (if it has one). For example, a suspend function should not start a network call and return without waiting for the result before returning. But by waiting, I mean by suspending the coroutine until the result is received, not blocking the thread.

Comment: @TenFour4 Ok forget the fact that they're _suspend_ calls (I'm dealing with code that's already been written). But the calls are asynch hence the premise to this question. Not interested in concurrency. Back to back calls does not seem to guarantee sequentiality but introduces a race condition. And I have reread this many times but I can't make out what you're trying to state ..."For example, a suspend function should not start a network call and return without waiting for the result before returning. But by waiting, I mean by suspending the coroutine until the result is received, not blo.."

Comment: Whether they are suspend functions or not, sequential functions in a coroutine return before the next line of code is run, just like code that is not in a coroutine. However, the term “async” in Kotlin or Java implies that the function starts an operation on another thread and then returns, likely before the work on that other thread is completed. If *that* is what you’re concerned about, since you didn’t write those other functions, then you’re right. There’s no mechanism for the coroutine to know when that background task is complete.

Comment: But marking a function `suspend` implies that it will not do that. The function should not return until that work is done. But it shouldn’t block the thread while it waits, either. If the background work is done using a callback-based API, you can use that in a suspend function using `suspendCoroutine()` or `suspendCancelableCoroutjne()`. If it simply blocking work, you can wrap it in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` to suspend the coroutine while it does that blocking work.

Comment: Typically, an asynchronous function has a callback parameter. Without any callback, then there would be no mechanism for knowing when the asynchronous work is done, with or without coroutines. If it does have a callback, then standard practice is to create a suspending overload of that function that uses `suspendCancelableCoroutine()` to wrap a call to the original function and suspend the coroutine until the result is received in the callback.

Comment: The doSomethingUsefulOneAsync() and doSomethingUsefulTwoAsync() for argument sake are APIs that cannot be altered and most likely have an underlying retrofit component that executes network calls. In your opinion would executing doSomethingUsefulOneAsync() and doSomethingUsefulTwoAsync() back-to-back guarantee sequential execution every time?

Comment: If the first function does not provide a callback for when it’s complete, and if it is not a suspend function that returns only after it is complete, then no, there is no way to prevent a race condition. But why would anyone write a function like that?

Comment: Ok. Looks like there's little for me to do. Reverse engineering this API call I can detect it as a _suspend_ call but it is still asynchronous so it's contradictory in nature.

Comment: If it’s from an open source library I can take a look. [Here's an example](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/fbf1225e28e2094bec35f587b8933748b705d167/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/KotlinExtensions.kt#L86) of a proper suspend function version of an asynchronous function, which uses `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to cause the suspend function to wait for the result before returning.

Answer (score 0):

Using async with each call will start a separate coroutine, which eventually leads to structured concurrent execution.

```
val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
val two = async { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }
println("The answer is ${one.await() + two.await()}")
```

Just using launch and calling both calls in the same coroutine ensures they are executed sequentially because code inside coroutine is same as regular code and executes sequentially.

```
launch {
 val one = doSomethingUsefulOne()
 val two = doSomethingUsefulTwo()
 println("The answer is ${one + two}")
}
```